# Which operation is faster: filter or withColumn with when?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Which one is more performant?

1. `filter` approach

   ```scala
   val df1 = df
     .filter('operation === true)
     .withColumn("operation2", lit(null))
   ```
2. `withColumn`/`when` approach

   ```scala
   val df2 = df.withColumn('operation2, when('operation === true, null))
   ```

Comment: You can not compare 1 & 2 because their output will be different. `df1` will only have the rows where `operation` is `true` and `df2` will return the entire dataframe.

Comment: @philantrovert Does this really matter? It's true that the less data the computation could be faster, but we can put that detail aside, can't we?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski sure, we can. I'm just saying a better comparison would be 1 vs `df.withColumn("operation2", when('operation === true, null).otherwise(0)).filter("operation 2 is null")`

Answer (score 1):

Putting the numbers of rows in the output aside (they could be different), I'm sure the performance would be same (or very comparable). The reason is that there's no interdependency between stages and tasks so the computations are as parallel as possible. They are both map-only computations.

In order to get a better understanding of this and other structured queries, use `explain` or simply web UI to review (and compare) physical plans.